# Citing a source multiple times in one paragraph using in-text references in APA style?

Tags: citations

What is the standardized approach to cite one source more than once within the same paragraph and without a second source?

I am aware of constructions such as "Smith (2010) developed X (p. 10). She concluded ..."

But is there an alternative approach when not using the "Author (year) ... (p.Z)" construction depicted above?

Can you alternatively write "The model X describes ... (Smith, 2010, p.10). Furthermore, something else (p.29)." in APA-style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this website](https://libguides.tru.ca/c.php?g=714411&p=5093126#:%7E:text=When%20citing%20the%20work%20of,%2C%20again%2C%20at%20the%20end.)

> When citing the work of the same author multiple times in one paragraph, you do not need to reference the author at the end of each sentence. That would look clunky and make your writing stilted. Instead, introduce the author with a full in-text citation at the beginning of the paragraph and then, again, at the end. For the body of the paragraph, you can refer to the author by name or pronoun.
>
> Example:
>
> According to Spitzer's (2010) study the effects of radiation on humans
> presents...Spitzer's study developed the guidelines needed to
> test...The most important find in his study was that....Spitzer
> concluded the benefit of radiation...The evidence that proves these
> guidelines work (Spitzer, 2010).

Comment: The proposed sentence structure is exactly what I wanted to find an alternative for.
The "Author (year) claims ...." construction is what I want to avoid in my specific case.